# Windows 10 update shows something went wrong try reopening settings later

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I don't know how this happened. I was using my pc as always but the next day i found this.
[image: Something went wrong try reopening settings later]

Comment: So, did you try re-opening setting later (probably after a day or two) and found the same error?

Comment: @Sanu_012 This error has come today only and I have restarted my PC many time since morning but it shows the same thing. I am using Windows 10 V2004 Build 19041.172

Comment: "something went wrong" Geez, You think Microsoft could give additional details.

Comment: On this [page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) of the Microsoft website you can find the Update Assistant and a tool to create a bootable installation media (USB or DVD)

Comment: Hi everyone! Um... I don't know what this problem was but it got fixed today automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simply go to CMD and run it as administrator
2. Now write " SFC /scannow " wait for 2 to 5 seconds
3. Check if "**Update Orchestrator Service**" is set to "disabled" and change to "Auto" ( Windows update bloker 1.1 can disable this service but not re-enable fixed in 1.5   )
4. After the scan completes, clean boots your PC ( For clean boot help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows )
   !

Comment: that don't help me sfc /scannow

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this 3rd party tool, [StopUpdates10](https://greatis.com/stopupdates10/)

Once downloaded and installed, just run StopUpdates10 and press the [Restore Windows Update] button and wait for the confirmation message to appear that says "Windows Update is not blocked" Once confirmed, just close the app and check Windows Update if it's been fixed and restored.

> [image: Screenshot#1]

> [image: Screenshot#2]

> [image: Screenshot#3]

> [image: Screenshot#4]

Comment: You should [edit] and add a description, otherwise this looks like spam

Comment: The author of the question wants to update Windows.  How does this answer their question?

Comment: Well, you can't get convenience updates from Microsoft if Windows Update is blocked and for some reason the [Check for updates] button is inaccessible. That's why I share this pretty nifty 3rd party tool from Greatis to restore the Windows Update feature as it used to be. Just like Windows Update feature, this tool can also control updates. But the sole purpose for this post, is to provide a hassle-free aid for Windows Update issue that says "Something went wrong. Try to reopen settings later" on Windows Update. And as for me, this tool is the simplest mean to mend this issue in particular.

Comment: @PrecastClockDJCami Hi! Even if your answer is correct you have not explained how to use this 3rd party tool so I don't know if this is useful. Also the problem was fixed automatically without the use of any third party tools and since then I am unable to recreate the problem. So even if your answer is correct I can't verify it. Here I would like to like to ask for help from other contributors out there to comment if this fix worked or not. But even before that please make the answer more explicit else I'll have to flag it.

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory i guess. It doesn't need a detailed instructions on how to use it. You just simply download the app/tool, install, run, then press [Restore Windows Update], wait for the confirmation message to appear that says Windows Update is not blocked. Once confirmed, you'll just simply close the app after that and check Windows Update to see if the StopUpdates10 app restored the Windows Update as it used to be.

Comment: this helped me restoring my windows updates. post IS self explanatory @CrispyCon

Comment: Sir... you just saved my day thank you so much! I've tried lots of solutions for this problem for few days. I've installed the software you recommended from here:
https://greatis.com/stopupdates10/download.htm
and could fix the update problem. Cheers

Comment: Same for me gents, recommending this pretty handy app/util is the least i can do. Kudos to Greatis Software!

Comment: Thank you for the solution provided. It's pretty easy. Thanks!